# Increase size of .navbar-brand class in bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, fonts

I am using `bootstrap` and have this line in my html code

`<a class="navbar-brand" style="font-weight: bold">Brand Name</a>`

I want to `increase the font size` and therefore I modified it to

`<a class="navbar-brand" style="font-weight: bold;font-size: larger">Brand Name</a>`.

However this doesn't change anything. What am I doing incorrectly. I am assuming `bootstrap css is overriding my commands`, how do I force it to `increase the font size`? Thank you.

working Snippet (I want to increase the size of Brand Name in website)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
 <head>
  <title> Brand Name</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="MyStyleSheet.css" />
 </head>
 
 <body >
  <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
   <div class="container-fluid">
    <!---logo-->
    <div class="navbar-header">
     <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
      <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
     </button>
     <a class="navbar-brand" style="font-weight: bold">Brand Name</a>
    </div>

    

    <!--menu Item here-->
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
     <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active">
       <a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">About Us</a>
      </li>

      <li>
       <a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">Projects</a>
      </li>
     </ul>

     <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li>
       <a href="#" style="font-weight: bold">Contact</a>
      </li>
     </ul>
    </div>
   </div>
  </nav>

 </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a working example of your code (HTML/CSS/JS) in a [Snippet](https://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/09/introducing-runnable-javascript-css-and-html-code-snippets/). See [mcve] and [ask].

Comment: @vanburen I added the snippet.

Answer (score 2):

> **larger, smaller**
>
> Larger or smaller than the parent element's font size, by roughly the
>   ratio used to separate the absolute size keywords above.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/font-size)

You're most likely not seeing any increase in the size of the font because `font-size: larger` is inheriting it's base size from `body` set by Bootstrap which is 14px, `navbar-brand` is 18px by default so you're actually **decreasing** the font-size by using `larger`. If you inspect the `navbar-brand` class when applying larger, it's size is computed at 16.8px.

You can always just set it's size with px, em or rem though.

See working Example Snippet.

```css
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-brand {
  font-weight: bold;
  font-size: 2.5rem;
}
.navbar.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li {
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#mainNavBar">
        <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
        <span class="icon-bar"> </span>
      </button>
      <a class="navbar-brand">Brand Name</a>
    </div>
    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNavBar">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
        <li class="active">
          <a href="#">About Us</a>
        </li>
        <li>
          <a href="#">Projects</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
        <li>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Thanks I understand the issue now.